# High level email parsing library for Python

Tags: library, python, email

Python has a email module in the standard library.

But this library is still very low-level.

For example getting the unicode string from a mail needs coding: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4157899/633961

I think this should be **one** method call. Not more.

Is there a high level library for parsing email in Python?

Comment: I have no experience with this, but am I to assume you've already done a Google search the the obvious hits like https://pypi.org/project/mail-parser/ and https://github.com/mailgun/flanker aren't appropriate?

Comment: I am looking for a recommendation. Copy+Paste from pypi is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search returned the mail-parser library which looks nice and succinct.

https://pypi.org/project/mail-parser/

From the docs:

```
mail-parser takes as input a raw email and generates a parsed object.
The properties of this object are the same name of RFC headers:
 bcc
 cc
 date
 delivered_to
 from_ (not from because is a keyword of Python)
 message_id
 received
 reply_to
 subject
 to
```